# FoxPro ODBC's giving zero on numeric fields instead of null

Tags: java, mysql, odbc, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am developing a foxpro to mysql migration tool and using foxpro ODBC driver for database connection and querying. I have been successfully executing select statement with ODBC driver. But it's giving me zero in numeric fields instead of null. In DBF file I checked, there's no data in that certain column with is numeric data type, but giving me zero.

Any suggestion for this problem and it's solution would be appreciated.

Thanks
Mani

Comment: Show us some example data and the code you used to reteive the values

Comment: Can you customize foxpro query?

Comment: Which version of FoxPro is the database. As far as I remember NULL was only introduced in FP3.0, prior to that fields were left blank & I believe ADO/ODBC drivers did not recognize that as NULL & returned an appropriate default value for the field type - 0 for numeric, false for logical, etc.

Comment: @PaulF: Oh now I understand. The DBF files were built by FoxPro 2.6 and I am using latest ODBC driver supporting Visual FoxPro 6. Can you recommend some data access tools/techniques compatible with FoxPro 2.6. I was using ODBC because I have a very limited time.

Comment: It may be worth checking the VFP OLEDB driver - I think that makes a better go at treating blanks as nulls, though it is several years since I have needed to transfer data from FoxPro tables.

Comment: @PaulF: I just tried OLEDB driver but found same issue. And also I found in one of the article that OLEDB driver itself uses ODBC under the hood. Anyway thanks PaulF, Soana, and Krismorte for your effort and help. I will keep on searching for it's solution. If found any, I will let you guys know about it.

Comment: I have seen suggestions that casting fields to char in the query & then checking for blanks may work. I can't find the link right now and I think that was for Date fields though, so not sure if it would work for numeric fields.

Comment: In a newly-created record in FoxPro 2.6, a numeric field is filled with blanks (character 0x20), but FoxPro itself interprets this as 0.  It doesn't surprise me that ODBC drivers treat it the same way.  As PaulF says, the concept of NULL didn't exist in the language at that point.  If you really want to differentiate between an actual value of 0 and uninitialized data, you may have to write code to interpret the DBF yourself.  The structure is pretty simple and well-documented.

Comment: @LAK: You FoxPro 2.6 platform (not only database) itself interprets blanks as zero?

Comment: @Mani-Rai  Numeric fields in the DBF format were/are actually stored as ASCII characters.  A Numeric field with no value stored to it literally contains all blanks, which you can see if you inspect the .DBF file using a hex viewer such as V (http://www.fileviewer.com).  All versions of FoxPro will treat that value as 0. I'm assuming that by 'platform' vs. database you mean the file format.  dBase and Clipper would have behaved the same way (I'm 99% sure of that).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Numeric values can be stored as a Character representation of the number or as a 'true' numeric (Integer or Float).

Once a Foxpro/Visual Foxpro data table field is created in a data table, it is initially Blank (not NULL) - no matter the field format with the exception of an Integer field type which is o.

> I am developing a foxpro **to** mysql migration tool and using foxpro ODBC driver for database connection and querying. I have been successfully executing select statement with ODBC driver

You do not indicate if you are writing your code in VFP or not, but if you were you would not need to be using ODBC to acquire the VFP data.

Help us better understand what you are doing and how so that we can give you better suggestions.